# Difference between indexing with $ and [[]] ???

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

i have a question regarding indexing a dataframe in R. This is the Code:

```
Gewicht <- data %>%
    group_by(data[[376]]) %>%
    summarise(weights = mean(data[[10190]], na.rm = TRUE))


Gewicht2 <- data %>%
    group_by(data[[376]]) %>%
    summarise(weights = mean(Weights, na.rm = TRUE))


a <- seq(1:10)
b <- rep(c("male", "female"),5)
c <- seq(1:10)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
data$c <- as.numeric(data$c)

newdata <- data %>%
    group_by(data[[2]]) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(c, na.rm = TRUE))

newdata2 <- data %>%
    group_by(data[[2]]) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(data[[3]], na.rm = TRUE))

print(newdata)
print(newdata2)
```

I get different results for both dataframes. The desired result in the "newdata". Can you tell me WHY i get different values for these two calculations?
I need brackets for a more complex custom function, but it seems it writes the mean for the whole dataframe, where i would hope to get the mean for each group. 
How to use [] or [[]] correctly here?

Comment: nothing to do with your question, but dont use `as.data.frame(cbind` - just use `data.frame`

Comment: Hey use `?"["` R has some build-in documentation to help their users.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- rep(c("male", "female"),5)
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)


data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
data$c <- as.numeric(as.character(data$c))

c
data$c

print(newdata)
print(newdata2)

newdata <- data %>%
    group_by(data[[2]]) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(c, na.rm = TRUE))

newdata2 <- data %>%
    group_by(data[[2]]) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(data[[3]], na.rm = TRUE))

newdata
newdata2
```

updated code, still different results :(

Answer (score 0):

Gewicht <- aggregate(data[[varGewicht]], by=list(data[[varx]]), FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)

Aggregate function works :-)